# Ethernet Speed am trying to get from driver through ioctl is constant say 57872Mbps,why?

Tags: c

am trying to read the speed of ethernet that is up on my device though am connecting 100mbps cable its reading same constant value 57872 or some junk value or 0 always....
the program logic  i made is as follows it wont consist all the code only bit part of it:

```
void get_link_config_res(void)
{
    int i=0;
    FILE *fp;
    int ret_val;
    char in_buf[200];
    char in_buf1[64];

    unsigned char interface_name[10];
    int sock_id;
    struct ifreq ir;
    struct sockaddr_in *sin = (void *) &ir.ifr_ifru.ifru_addr;
    struct sockaddr_in *nmsk = (void *) &ir.ifr_ifru.ifru_netmask;
    //struct sockaddr_in *brdcast = (void *) &ir.ifr_ifru.ifru_broadaddr;
    static int_net_cfg_t int_eth,int_wifi;
    int_netcfg_array_t temp_netcfg,wifi_netcfg;

    static __u8 mac_address[6];
    char *temp_buf;
    struct ethtool_cmd edata;

    if(verify_host_link_status(ETH_0) == SET_FLAG)
    {
        /* get Ethernet link status */
        memset(&ir, 0, sizeof(ir));
        memset(in_buf, 0, sizeof(in_buf));
        memset(in_buf1, 0, sizeof(in_buf1));
        memset(mac_address, 0, sizeof(mac_address));
        memset(interface_name, 0, sizeof(interface_name));

        strcpy(ir.ifr_name, ETHERNET);


        /* socket creation (IPV4) */
        sock_id = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
        if(sock_id < 0)
        {
            SPX_DEBUG_3("cannot open socket \n");
        }

        strcpy(ir.ifr_ifrn.ifrn_name, ir.ifr_name);

        ir.ifr_data = (char *)&edata;
        //printf("Ethernet speed 1=",ir.ifr_data);
        ret_val = ioctl(sock_id, SIOCGIFHWADDR, &ir);
        //printf("retval of ioctl is = %d\n",ret_val);
        memcpy(mac_address, &ir.ifr_ifru.ifru_hwaddr.sa_data, 6);

        for(i=0; i<6; i++)
        {
            temp_netcfg.hwaddr[i] = mac_address[i];
        }
        mac2string(temp_netcfg.hwaddr, &in_buf1);

        sprintf(in_buf,"echo mac_address=%s > %s", in_buf1, ETHERNET_PARAMS_FILE);
        system(in_buf);

        edata.cmd = ETHTOOL_GSET;
        /*eth speed*/
        ret_val = ioctl(sock_id, SIOCETHTOOL, &ir);
        memset(in_buf, 0, sizeof(in_buf));
        //printf("Ethernet speed=%d",edata.speed);
        switch (edata.speed)
        {
            case SPEED_10:
                sprintf(in_buf,"echo speed=10Mbps >> %s",ETHERNET_PARAMS_FILE);
                system(in_buf);
                //printf("10Mbps\n");
                break;
            case SPEED_100:
                //printf("100Mbps\n");
                sprintf(in_buf,"echo speed=100Mbps >> %s",ETHERNET_PARAMS_FILE);
                system(in_buf);
                break;
            case SPEED_1000:
                //printf("1Gbps\n");
                sprintf(in_buf,"echo speed=1Gbps >> %s",ETHERNET_PARAMS_FILE);
                system(in_buf);
                break;
            case SPEED_10000:
                //printf("10Gbps\n");
                sprintf(in_buf,"echo speed=10Gbps >> %s",ETHERNET_PARAMS_FILE);
                system(in_buf);
                break;
            default:
                //printf("Speed returned is ____%d\n", edata.speed);
                sprintf(in_buf,"echo speed=%dMbps >> %s",edata.speed, ETHERNET_PARAMS_FILE);
                system(in_buf);
                break;
        }

        memset(in_buf, 0, sizeof(in_buf));

        /* get the IP address */
        ret_val = ioctl(sock_id, SIOCGIFADDR, &ir);
        int_eth.ipaddr.s_addr = sin->sin_addr.s_addr;
        /*To get Ip address in ASCII format*/
        temp_buf = inet_ntoa(int_eth.ipaddr);
        strcpy (in_buf, temp_buf);
        sprintf(in_buf,"echo ip_address=%s >> %s",temp_buf, ETHERNET_PARAMS_FILE);
        system(in_buf);

        memset(in_buf, 0, sizeof(in_buf));
         /*subnet mask*/
        ret_val = ioctl(sock_id, SIOCGIFNETMASK, &ir);
        int_eth.netmask.s_addr = nmsk->sin_addr.s_addr;

        /*To get subnet mask in ASCII format*/
        temp_buf = inet_ntoa(int_eth.netmask);
        strcpy (in_buf, temp_buf);
        sprintf(in_buf,"echo subnet_mask=%s >> %s",temp_buf, ETHERNET_PARAMS_FILE);
        system(in_buf);
        close(sock_id);
    }
    else
    {
        /*Host is not connected, to the  Ethernet interface.*/
        //printf("Ethernet Interface is not connected...\n");
        memset(in_buf1, 0, sizeof(in_buf1));
        strcpy(in_buf1, "NONE");
        sprintf(in_buf,"echo mac_address=%s > %s", in_buf1, ETHERNET_PARAMS_FILE);
        system(in_buf);

        sprintf(in_buf,"echo speed=%s >> %s", in_buf1, ETHERNET_PARAMS_FILE);
        system(in_buf);

        sprintf(in_buf,"echo ip_address=%s >> %s",in_buf1, ETHERNET_PARAMS_FILE);
        system(in_buf);

        sprintf(in_buf,"echo subnet_mask=%s >> %s",in_buf1, ETHERNET_PARAMS_FILE);
        system(in_buf);
        //status = CLEAR_FLAG;
    }
}
```

please help me out over this..... thanks in advance.....

Comment: Try the previous example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872058/get-link-speed-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

```
ret_val = ioctl(sock_id, SIOCETHTOOL, &ir);
```

You're *halfway* there, at least. You appear to recognise the fact that the `ioctl` may fail but you don't carry through and actually *check* the return value.

Given that your text indicates the value is *always* wrong (" 57872 or some junk value or 0 always"), I'd say it's a safe bet that you're getting back a consistent error code, such as `EOPNOTSUPP`.

Modify the code to check that *first,* then run it again.