# Get network link type and speed programmatically in C

Tags: c, linux, networking, network-programming

I wonder if there is a more compact way to find the link speed and the type (wireless, ethernet) of a network interface in Linux, rather than just open and read the `/sys/class/net/eth0/type` and `/sys/class/net/eth0/speed` files for example.

If not, can anyone tell me where I can find the number that `/sys/class/net/eth0/type` returns, in which network types corresponds?

**EDIT:** It get even worse! After some  experiments with wireless, `/sys/class/net/wlan0/type` returns also 1, and `/sys/class/net/wlan0/speed` does not exists and I had to take the link speed from `/sys/class/net/wlan0/wireless/link` which some times returns a speed that is not right. For example in a 54Mbits card sometimes returns 55.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Someone asked similar questions here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872058/get-link-speed-programmatically

Comment: Yeah, but that question has to do about the speed of the ethernet. In my case the link my be also wireless. Anyway, I think I found a way. I will post it when I finish my program.

Comment: Unfortunately, I ended parsing the output from iw and ethtool... Not the best solution, but I had no spare time...

Answer (score 0):

This only solves half your problem but with the library libpcap you can open a live pcap_t and then call pcap_datalink. That will give you the link type. (DLT_IEEE802_11, DLT_EN10MB, etc)

- http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap3_man.html
- http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/pcap_datalink/

Comment: I think that the link type DLT_IEEE802_11 is available only when the interface is on monitor mode. Otherwise libpcap returns it as a standard ethernet link. But I will try it, just to be sure! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To get the link type (Ethernet, 802.11, etc.) you can use the `SIOCGIFHWADDR` ioctl. The ioctl returns one of `ARPHRD_` values (defined in `net/if_arp.h`) in the `sa_family` of the `struct sockaddr`. See [man netdevice(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netdevice.7.html) for more details.

See an example (not tested):

```
/**
 * Get network interface link type
 * @param name the network interface name
 * @return <0 error code on error, the ARPHRD_ link type otherwise
 */
int get_link_type(const char* name)
{
    int rv;
    int fd;
    struct ifreq ifr;

    if (strlen(name) >= IFNAMSIZ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Name '%s' is too long\n", name);
        return -ENAMETOOLONG;
    }
    strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, name, IFNAMSIZ);

    fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP);
    if (fd < 0)
        return fd;

    rv = ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFHWADDR, &ifr);
    close(fd);
    if (rv < 0)
        return rv;

    {
        char *type = "Unknown";
        switch (ifr.ifr_hwaddr.sa_family)
        {
        case ARPHRD_ETHER:  type = "Ethernet"; break;
        case ARPHRD_IEEE80211:  type = "802.11"; break;
        /* add more cases here */
        }
        printf("Link type is: %s\n", type);
    }

    return ifr.ifr_hwaddr.sa_family;
}
```

To get the link speed you need the `SIOCETHTOOL` ioctl as discussed for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14264371/how-to-get-nic-details-from-a-c-program).