# How to get NIC details from a C program?

Tags: c, linux

I want to get the following details for all the NICs attached to my computer:

1) Interface name (eg. eth0)

2) Interface Number (like in [Windows](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080517041705AAOmJPu)) if such a thing exists in Linux

3) NIC bandwidth capacity and mode (eg. 1Gb/s full duplex)

Comment: [using C code to get same info as ifconfig](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951257/using-c-code-to-get-same-info-as-ifconfig), also chekcout [netdevice](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl7_netdevice.htm)

Comment: @Joe: It doesn't tell you 2 and 3.

Comment: Its a start until you get an answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use [`getifaddrs()`/`freeifaddrs()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html) to obtain a linked list of all interfaces, then `ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFINDEX, struct ifreq *)` to obtain the interface index for each. Since the interfaces are consecutive and always listed (regardless of whether or they are up (active) or not), I choose to enumerate them with a loop using `ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFNAME, struct ifreq *)` instead.  In all cases `fd` is an `AF_INET` socket.

To obtain the duplex and speed of the interface, you need to use the `ioctl(fd, SIOCETHTOOL, struct ifreq *)` with the `ifr_data` pointing to a `struct ethtool_cmd` having `cmd = ETHTOOL_GSET`.

The ioctls should return -1 if they fail, and a nonnegative value (zero, I believe) if success.

Here is an example program:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <linux/ethtool.h>
#include <linux/sockios.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct interface {
    int     index;
    int     flags;      /* IFF_UP etc. */
    long    speed;      /* Mbps; -1 is unknown */
    int     duplex;     /* DUPLEX_FULL, DUPLEX_HALF, or unknown */
    char    name[IF_NAMESIZE + 1];
};

static int get_interface_common(const int fd, struct ifreq *const ifr, struct interface *const info)
{
    struct ethtool_cmd  cmd;
    int                 result;

    /* Interface flags. */
    if (ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFFLAGS, ifr) == -1)
        info->flags = 0;
    else
        info->flags = ifr->ifr_flags;

    ifr->ifr_data = (void *)&cmd;
    cmd.cmd = ETHTOOL_GSET; /* "Get settings" */
    if (ioctl(fd, SIOCETHTOOL, ifr) == -1) {
        /* Unknown */
        info->speed = -1L;
        info->duplex = DUPLEX_UNKNOWN;
    } else {
        info->speed = ethtool_cmd_speed(&cmd);
        info->duplex = cmd.duplex;
    }

    do {
        result = close(fd);
    } while (result == -1 && errno == EINTR);
    if (result == -1)
        return errno;

    return 0;
}

int get_interface_by_index(const int index, struct interface *const info)
{
    int             socketfd, result;
    struct ifreq    ifr;

    if (index < 1 || !info)
        return errno = EINVAL;

    socketfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP);
    if (socketfd == -1)
        return errno;

    ifr.ifr_ifindex = index;
    if (ioctl(socketfd, SIOCGIFNAME, &ifr) == -1) {
        do {
            result = close(socketfd);
        } while (result == -1 && errno == EINTR);
        return errno = ENOENT;
    }

    info->index = index;
    strncpy(info->name, ifr.ifr_name, IF_NAMESIZE);
    info->name[IF_NAMESIZE] = '\0';

    return get_interface_common(socketfd, &ifr, info);
}

int get_interface_by_name(const char *const name, struct interface *const info)
{
    int             socketfd, result;
    struct ifreq    ifr;

    if (!name || !*name || !info)
        return errno = EINVAL;

    socketfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP);
    if (socketfd == -1)
        return errno;

    strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, name, IF_NAMESIZE);
    if (ioctl(socketfd, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifr) == -1) {
        do {
            result = close(socketfd);
        } while (result == -1 && errno == EINTR);
        return errno = ENOENT;
    }

    info->index = ifr.ifr_ifindex;
    strncpy(info->name, name, IF_NAMESIZE);
    info->name[IF_NAMESIZE] = '\0';

    return get_interface_common(socketfd, &ifr, info);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct interface    iface;
    int                 arg;
    int                 status = 0;

    if (argc > 1 && (!strcmp(argv[1], "-h") || !strcmp(argv[1], "--help"))) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s { -h | --help }\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "       %s\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "       %s INTERFACE ...\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (argc > 1) {
        for (arg = 1; arg < argc; arg++) {
            if (get_interface_by_name(argv[arg], &iface) != 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: No such interface.\n", argv[arg]);
                status = 1;
                continue;
            }

            printf("%s: Interface %d", iface.name, iface.index);
            if (iface.flags & IFF_UP)
                printf(", up");
            if (iface.duplex == DUPLEX_FULL)
                printf(", full duplex");
            else
            if (iface.duplex == DUPLEX_HALF)
                printf(", half duplex");
            if (iface.speed > 0)
                printf(", %ld Mbps", iface.speed);
            printf("\n");
        }

    } else {
        for (arg = 1; ; arg++) {
            if (get_interface_by_index(arg, &iface) != 0)
                break;

            printf("%s: Interface %d", iface.name, iface.index);
            if (iface.flags & IFF_UP)
                printf(", up");
            if (iface.duplex == DUPLEX_FULL)
                printf(", full duplex");
            else
            if (iface.duplex == DUPLEX_HALF)
                printf(", half duplex");
            if (iface.speed > 0)
                printf(", %ld Mbps", iface.speed);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

    return status;
}
```

If you save the above as `iflist.c`, you can compile it using

```
gcc -W -Wall -O3 iflist.c -o iflist
```

To see the usage, run `iflist -h`. To list all interfaces, run it without parameters:

```
./iflist
```

The above will use the enumeration method I described. To list only specific interfaces, run it naming the interfaces:

```
./iflist eth0 lo
```

Duplex and speed is only listed for ethernet interfaces, of course.

---

Edited to add:

If the above program does not supply the bandwidth and mode for an interface, here is a simplified version which reports the exact reason (errors). This one takes the interface names as commandline parameters; it does not enumerate interfaces.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <linux/ethtool.h>
#include <linux/sockios.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int ethernet_interface(const char *const name,
                       int *const index, int *const speed, int *const duplex)
{
    struct ifreq        ifr;
    struct ethtool_cmd  cmd;
    int                 fd, result;

    if (!name || !*name) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: NULL interface name.\n");
        fflush(stderr);
        return errno = EINVAL;
    }

    if (index)  *index = -1;
    if (speed)  *speed = -1;
    if (duplex) *duplex = -1;

    fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (fd == -1) {
        const int err = errno;
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Cannot create AF_INET socket: %s.\n", name, strerror(err));
        fflush(stderr);
        return errno = err;
    }

    strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, name, sizeof ifr.ifr_name);
    ifr.ifr_data = (void *)&cmd;
    cmd.cmd = ETHTOOL_GSET;
    if (ioctl(fd, SIOCETHTOOL, &ifr) < 0) {
        const int err = errno;
        do {
            result = close(fd);
        } while (result == -1 && errno == EINTR);
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: SIOCETHTOOL ioctl: %s.\n", name, strerror(err));
        return errno = err;
    }

    if (speed)
        *speed = ethtool_cmd_speed(&cmd);

    if (duplex)
        switch (cmd.duplex) {
        case DUPLEX_HALF: *duplex = 0; break;
        case DUPLEX_FULL: *duplex = 1; break;
        default:
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: Unknown mode (0x%x).\n", name, cmd.duplex);
            fflush(stderr);
            *duplex = -1;
        }

    if (index && ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifr) >= 0)
        *index = ifr.ifr_ifindex;

    do {
        result = close(fd);
    } while (result == -1 && errno == EINTR);
    if (result == -1) {
        const int err = errno;
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Error closing socket: %s.\n", name, strerror(err));
        return errno = err;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int  arg, speed, index, duplex;

    if (argc < 2 || !strcmp(argv[1], "-h") || !strcmp(argv[1], "--help")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [ -h | --help ]\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "       %s INTERFACE ...\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        return 0;
    }

    for (arg = 1; arg < argc; arg++) {
        if (ethernet_interface(argv[arg], &index, &speed, &duplex))
            return 1;

        if (index == -1)
            printf("%s: (no interface index)", argv[arg]);
        else
            printf("%s: interface %d", argv[arg], index);

        if (speed == -1)
            printf(", unknown bandwidth");
        else
            printf(", %d Mbps bandwidth", speed);

        if (duplex == 0)
            printf(", half duplex.\n");
        else if (duplex == 1)
            printf(", full duplex.\n");
        else
            printf(", unknown mode.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Questions?

Comment: Here is the output I get $ ./iflist 
lo: Interface 1, up
eth0: Interface 2, up

Comment: I tried it on some other machines also. I don't get the bandwidth and mode.

Comment: @Bruce: The reason for that is that your interfaces do not support the `SIOCETHTOOL` ioctl, which is used to obtain the mode and bandwidth. What kind of interfaces you have on those machines? Infiniband? Does `ethtool eth0` yield the bandwidth and mode on those?

Comment: @Bruce: Scratch that; infiniband et cetera do seem to support the ioctls. Could you please compile and run the second example code I just added? After checking on an older RHEL system, I noticed that I get `eth0: SIOCETHTOOL ioctl: Operation not permitted.` if I run it as a non-root user. This is because on some systems only root is permitted to obtain such detailed information on the interfaces. You can verify if this applies to your system too, by running the example code as root (using `su` or `sudo`).

Comment: I get the same error "eth0: SIOCETHTOOL ioctl: Operation not supported." even when I run the code as root.

Comment: @Bruce: That means your interface does not support the ethtool ioctls. Do you know of any command that actually does yield the bandwidth and mode? Have you tried `ethtool` yet? Do note that for example, virtual machine network interfaces do not really have bandwidth or mode, since they do not make any sense for a virtual interface. Similarly for other virtual and non-ethernet devices like loopback.

Comment: ethtool also gives an error. "virtual machine network interfaces do not really have bandwidth or mode" that explains it. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

(1) [getifaddrs()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html)

(2) [if_indextoname()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/if_indextoname), [if_nameindex()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/if_nameindex.3.html), [if_nametoindex()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/if_nametoindex.3.html)

(3) I'm not sure about this one but you might be able to get at it through [ioctl()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/ioctl.2.html) and one of the `SIOCGIF*` parameters or from `/proc`.

Answer (score 3):

the following link well explain the `getifaddrs` function with a working example

[getifaddrs()](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/manpages/3/getifaddrs.htm)

Answer (score 2):

```
ethtool eth1
```

this command will list all the details about eth1 including speed, duplex, port...

you can use popen() to get the output and map it.

> POPEN(3)                   Linux Programmer's Manual
>   POPEN(3)
>
> NAME
>          popen, pclose - pipe stream to or from a process
>
> SYNOPSIS
>          #include
>
> ```
>    FILE *popen(const char *command, const char *type);
> ```