# how to get current network link speed through c program

Tags: c, network-programming

when some packets are transmitted on our interface how get the current packet transmission speed through a c program and display it.

Currently im collecting statistics after complete traffic generation from /sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/tx_bytes and shoing speed using following formulae

speed = (tx_bytes*8)/(60*1024*1024) for showing in mbps (mega bits per second) but the actual speed shown on bmon (bandwidth monitor) program and what im getting using this calculation are different.

Comment: There is no standard C library for doing this.  Anything would be operating system dependent.  What platform are you trying to run this on?  I think you're looking at the actual number of bytes transmitted - which isn't going to give you the speed it's capable of.

Comment: Duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872058/get-link-speed-programmatically?lq=1
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777866/get-network-link-type-and-speed-programmatically-in-c