# iOS Get Link Speed (Router Speed Test)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, wifi

I want to test speed of connected router(wifi modem) from iOS app.

I've found something here [Get link speed programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872058/get-link-speed-programmatically) but could not found sockios.h and ethtool.h

Is it possible to port this code to Objective-C or is there another way?

--

Sorry for the missing info and my poor english.

I want to test link speed (tx rate) between ios device and connected wifi modem.

There was a property named txRate in CWInterface class. I want to get that data in Cocoa Touch.

```
/*!
* @property
* @abstract Current transmit rate (Mbps) of the CoreWLAN interface. 
* @discussion Dynamically queries the interface for the current transmit rate.
*/
@property(readonly) NSNumber *txRate NS_DEPRECATED_MAC(10_6, 10_7);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I've found the solution.

```
#include <ifaddrs.h>
#include <net/if.h>

+ (double)getRouterLinkSpeed
{
    BOOL   success;
    struct ifaddrs *addrs;
    const struct ifaddrs *cursor;
    const struct if_data *networkStatisc;

    double linkSpeed = 0;

    NSString *name = [[NSString alloc] init];

    success = getifaddrs(&addrs) == 0;
    if (success)
    {
        cursor = addrs;
        while (cursor != NULL)
        {
            name=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",cursor->ifa_name];

            if (cursor->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_LINK)
            {
                if ([name hasPrefix:@"en"])
                {
                    networkStatisc = (const struct if_data *) cursor->ifa_data;
                    linkSpeed = networkStatisc->ifi_baudrate;
                }
            }
            cursor = cursor->ifa_next;
        }
        freeifaddrs(addrs);
    }

    return linkSpeed;
}
```

Comment: I'm not able to compile on Xcode code which you have posted `+(double)getRouterLinkSpeed`.
Can you post the headers which need to be included.

Comment: #include <ifaddrs.h>
#include <net/if.h>

Comment: One more thing..is this speed in seconds or ms.What exactly this speed indicates.Actually I want to calculate the time taken to transfer my data in my app and want to show this estimated time to user.

Comment: always returns 0 for me

Comment: Actually it's a bit old code and was working fine on iOS 6 & 7. But i haven't tested on iOS 8 or 9.

Comment: for me also its return o only

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NSURLConnection` to connect to your test server and download a preset file of something like 1 MB. Use the NSURLConnection delegate `-connection:didReceiveData:` and `-connectionDidFinishLoading:`to track the download 'so far' and compute the download speed from that.

Comment: I don't want to test internet speed, i want to test only modem speed.

Comment: OK... ... ... ... what is the modem connected to?

Comment: @suleymancalik do you mean you want to test the connection speed between your device and the wifi router?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no official (or Apple approved) way to get LinkSpeed on iOS. There were loop holes in the past which were closed unfortunately.

The most similar metric you can use to estimate LinkSpeed is measure wifi speed by sending UDP packets on the local network and measuring their sending rate. This is called IP packet sending bit rate and is defined in this ITU standard https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-Y.1540/en

The iOS implementation of that wifi speed measurement is in our iOS SDK which you can find here:

https://github.com/speedchecker/speedchecker-sdk-ios

This implementation is the closest you can get to estimate router wifi speed without actually placing any payload files on the router itself.