# iOS:How to find connected Wifi band frequency(2.4 GHZ or 5 GHZ) in the iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have Wifi connected device which only work on 2.4 GHZ.I want to scan wifi frequency band and whenever user connect to 5 GHZ need to show alert to switch to 2.4 GHZ.I can't used private api as my app will be rejected in the appstore.Do we have any public Api to find the band?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. The way that your question is currently worded it will very likely be downvoted and closed by the community as it currently shows no research, no attempt and is very vague. Please edit your question and include some more information. Show what research you have done, show some code.

Comment: Not an answer, just a hint: have a look at the built-in SystemConfiguration library which can be used to retrieve various infos about the network connection, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31555640/how-to-get-wifi-ssid-in-ios9-after-captivenetwork-is-deprecated-and-calls-for-wi
I know it can be used to find out the network name, maybe there's also a way to get the bandwidth.

Comment: The answer is in this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20462324/how-to-get-the-current-connection-wifi-channel-frequency-in-ios/64822055#64822055